# Why can't my machine resolve local windows hostnames?

Tags: windows, samba

When I ping any local windows hostname from my Ubuntu machine I get "unable to resolve host", but when I ping from a windows machine it works fine. Why would this be? Samba & Miredo are installed

Answer (score 29):

To ping a netbios name in Ubuntu you need to add `wins` to `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. Run:

```
gksu gedit /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

And add `wins` to the line:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

So it looks like this:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns wins mdns4
```

Save the file, close the text editor, and ping away.

If that does not work, open `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, and uncomment the "name resolve order" line:

```
name resolve order = wins lmhosts bcast
```

after that, restart `nmbd smbd winbindd`.

Comment: I added wins but that didn't change anything. However, I noticed that if I add ".local" after some names it works (with or without the wins setting)... Do you know what's going on there?

Comment: plus in addition to nejode's answer (thanks nejode) I would also check your smb.conf I have added mine to my answer for comparison.

Comment: what you need to verify in the smb.conf is that your workgroup is the same as the one in the windows station

Comment: *The Paste you are looking for does not currently exist.*

Comment: @David: That's using the Avahi system to resolve your names, which the `mdns4` directives specify. That's a different system than Samba, so if you want Samba to work, you have to keep testing without the `.local` domain.

Comment: I would [place both `dns` and `wins` before any `mdns4` directives](http://askubuntu.com/a/97757/39012), unless you love Avahi.

Answer (score 8):

Running `apt-get install winbind` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 7):

You may have to install the package libnss-winbind to be able to find windows computers by hostname. Simply installing winbind may not work. See [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/380521/150853).

Comment: Beautiful, worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04.  Installing winbind by itself didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem, Ubuntu 14.04 trying to access PC with Windows 8. In addition to above recommendation I had to install `libnss-winbind`

```
sudo apt-get install libnss-winbind
```

Source: http://singularo.com/ubuntu-winbind-not-working

Comment: I'm running 18.04 and have been trying to solves this problem for almost a whole day. This was the (last) thing I was missing. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have [edited your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file](https://askubuntu.com/a/97757/39012) and [installed `winbind`](https://askubuntu.com/a/27874/39012) already ([`libnss-winbind`](https://askubuntu.com/a/487859/39012) or `samba-winbind`) and still have problems, you may need to [disable your NSCD (Name Service Cache Daemon)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/273721/13308).

Answer (score 1):

@Spivot +1

1. `sudo apt-get install winbind libnss-winbind`
2. `sudo vi /etc/nsswitch.conf`

   edit:

   `hosts: files dns wins myhostname`
3. `sudo vi /etc/samba/smb.conf`

edit:

```
[global]
wins server = x.x.x.x
name resolve order = host
```

Reboot for best results, or just:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart
```