# Windows hostnames are not resolved

Tags: 11.10, networking, samba

I know that [similar questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27541/why-cant-my-machine-resolve-local-windows-hostnames) has already been asked. However, as suggested in the answers to that question I have the `winbind` package installed and have `wins` in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns wins mdns4
```

Nevertheless, attempts to ping windows hostnames give

```
ping: unknown host <hostname>
```

Restarting `winbind` service doesn't help.

I have Ubuntu 11.10 and winbind 3.5.11.

Comment: Not clear by your question, but are you trying to access shared folders from windows machine???

Comment: @rao_555: no, just ping a windows machine

Comment: if you'r windows machine are in same network, you can directly ping the windows machine, you dont need winbind for that. The main use of winbind is for unified logon.

Comment: @rao_555: that's what I am doing, but the name is not resolved

Comment: check if your linux machine is in your network. check if you are able to ping the linux machine's ip-address from windows system. Also, check if you are able to ping windows machine ip-address

Comment: I did not have `mdns4` in my default `nsswitch.conf` (ubuntu 14.04), you don't need that; it also feels a little bit faster without.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue.  Changing the location of wins in `nslookup.conf` did not work, or possibly only got me part of the way there. Install the package `libnss-winbind` to be able to find windows computers by hostname.  I tested it with and without the package installed, and it is indeed necessary for resolving any windows hostname.

Comment: +1 could not resolve windows host names without this library (even if nmblookup works)

Comment: installing libnss-winbind was the key.

Answer (score 16):

To summarize the above, here's what I did to get it to work:

1. `sudo apt-get install winbind`
2. `sudo apt-get install libnss-winbind`
3. `sudo gedit /etc/nsswitch.conf` and append "wins" after "files"

   ```
   hosts:          files wins mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
   ```

Comment: Using 18.04.3 in 2019, and this is still the way to go! Be sure to restart the winbind service afterwards: `sudo systemctl restart winbind`

Answer (score 7):

The order of operands in the hosts definition in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is important. In your case, host name resolution is terminated by the [NOTFOUND=return] statement before WINS name resolution ever happens. Move 'wins' so it's just after 'files', and you should be good to go:

```
hosts:          files wins mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

[nmblookup](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/nmblookup.1.html) (part of the samba-common-bin package) is another useful troubleshooting tool for this situations--it can be used to manually verify that the hostname you're using is valid.

Comment: Placing `wins` before `[NOTFOUND=return]` breaks name resolution in  chrome and firefox.

Comment: How exactly is name resolution breaking? Do all name lookups fail to resolve, or just NetBIOS names?

Also, does ping work with the modified hosts line?

Comment: When I place `wins` before `[NOTFOUND=return]` the browser is unable to open `google.com` and other sites, so it's not only NetBIOS. When I change it back, sites open normally. The ping does work with the modified hosts line.

Comment: The 'wins' statement needs to go after 'files', not after 'mdns4_minimal'. If you put 'wins' after 'mdns4_minimal' and before '[NOTFOUND=return]', then you're telling the name resolution routines to return if the NetBIOS name isn't found, which skips dns. Try moving 'wins' so it's immediately after 'files'. If you still have issues, try moving 'dns' so it's before 'mdns_minimal' as well, like so: `hosts:          files dns wins mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4`

Comment: Mr cqcallaw
You should at least mention which config files we should change/edit

Comment: I was assuming the config file was obvious, since it was the only file mentioned in the original question. But, to avoid any confusion, I've updated my answer.