# How do I make Ubuntu a NetBIOS WINS server?

Tags: networking, windows, samba

We are creating a Windows CE based, mobile 6 solution. The solution pulls and uploads files to folders from the mobile device, to the server (which is Ubuntu). We don't have any other Windows machine (only Windows CE mobiles and Ubuntu server).

Now the mobile device can only access the folder through NetBIOS WINS supplied server names.

So we want our Ubuntu server to turn into a WINS server.

Ubuntu is not running WINS properly. For test we are trying to ping the server by name and is failing. We have tried almost everything but still not able to get the WINS going on the server.

We have followed this answer [Why can't my machine resolve local windows hostnames?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27541/why-cant-my-machine-resolve-local-windows-hostnames) and installed `libnss-winbind`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added

```
[global]
wins support = yes  
name resolve order = wins lmhosts hosts bcast
```

To your smb.conf?

You may not need anything but

```
name resolve order = wins
```

But the rest is explained in link below

For more info see [This section](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch07_03.html)

If you still can't get wins to work, you should be able to define the shares in

```
usr/local/samba/lib/LMHOSTS
```

An example LMHOSTS file

```
192.168.220.100 hydra
192.168.220.100 simple
192.168.220.101 phoenix
```

Its just like the /etc/host file, but instead of using hostname, your defining netbios shares