# Can't reach (ping) specific site

Tags: networking, server, dns

I have a pretty fresh Ubuntu 16.04 installation (1 day old) and would like to install some roundcube plugins via [composer](https://getcomposer.org/). The composer install always results in the following error:

> The
>   "https://plugins.roundcube.net/p/provider-2014%24a8c540d1f701cc29bc8690742f519b91ddc4e3f86f825a1dbe2757046fd5d24d.json" file could not be downloaded:
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo      failed: Name or service not
>   known

I've started debugging by pinging www.roundcube.net & plugins.roundcube.net which sometimes works and most of the times ends in `unknown host` messages. Feels like a lottery... Both sites are always reachable from any windows machine in the same network.

There are only 2 things I can think of, which I have modified regarding network functionality in my install:

1. Installed `winbind` & `libnss-winbind` and added `wins` to `/etc/nsswitch.conf` so that I can ping my windows machines with their hostnames (followed instructions from [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/27548/579685)). The complete `/etc/nsswitch.conf` looks like this:

```bsh
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns wins mdns4
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

2. Added the line `127.0.1.1 localhost.halumi.at` to `/etc/hosts` for local development reasons:

```bsh
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       nuc
127.0.1.1       localhost.halumi.at

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback fe00::0 ip6-localnet ff00::0
ip6-mcastprefix ff02::1 ip6-allnodes ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Please let me know if I can provide any other info!

Comment: have you tried downloading it with hand by clicking the link?

Comment: The browser shows the same behavior as pinging: Sometimes it opens the page, sometimes it shows the `Server not found` page. Manually downloading it won't help me since I can't force the `composer` script to only use local resources...

Comment: maybe it is a problem with the site?

Comment: Could be but since it's always reachable from other clients it doesn't seem to be likely to me...

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of downloading the file for you and putting it on github so you can still reach it (hopefully), just install git and type
`git clone https://github.com/ppigmans/json`

Comment: That's very kind of you, but like I said initially, the file is downloaded automatically by a `composer` script and I actually don't know if and where I can manually change the fetch URL. Also I guess there will be other files which need to be downloaded in the process which you'd also have to supply manually one after another. If I really don't find no other solution I could host the files myself (like you did in the github repo) and force downloading by creating a manual hosts route but I'm actually interested in a real solution the the cause (URL not reachable), not some workaround for it.

Comment: Here's an alternate idea, try installing 14.04 on a VM or somewhere else and try your method again, if it works then you know its a bug on 16.04

Comment: Ok, I will try that.