# Configure Azure Ubuntu VM to resolve windows hosts on the same network

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, dns, azure

I have deployed a new Azure Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS VM and the vNet is peered with an on-prem network with AD and windows servers.

I have tried all [answers listed here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27541/why-cant-my-machine-resolve-local-windows-hostnames) in an attempt to configure the Ubuntu VM to resolve the windows hosts on the same network, but none has worked. Looks like most of those solutions are outdated or may be not related to this recent Ubuntu version.

I don't have much Ubuntu experience and have run out of options...

Answer (score 0):

What really worked for me was:

1. Updated `/etc/systemd/resolved.config` to use the local network DNS servers

   ```
   [Resolve]
   DNS=10.0.11.xxx 10.0.12.xxx
   FallbackDNS=10.xx.x.xxx 168.63.129.16
   Domains=domain.net
   ```
2. Updated `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` to have the IP addresses for the local domain DNS servers as `nameserver` entries:

   ```
   nameserver 10.0.11.xxx
   nameserver 10.0.12.xxx 
   search domain.net reddog.microsoft.com
   ```